# How apply plugin works in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm not too sure how the `apply plugin` functionality works or why it's needed in gradle.

My app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.krousorati.truthordare"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha11"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
}
```

Here's my project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }   

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It appears it matches up with dependencies from the project gradle file, but I'm not exactly sure:

1. How it's targeting/finding the given plugin
2. Why it needs to `apply` it (and what `apply` is doing)

Any clarification on this would be great

Comment: what is aim from this Question??..and there is deference in Kotlin Version `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'` and  `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"`

Comment: The aim of this question is to understand how apply plugin works and why it is needed, as stated below my code.